# Regex - Substitute character in a matching substring

Tags: r, regex

Let's say I have the following string:

```
input = "askl jmsp wiqp;THIS IS A MATCH; dlkasl das, fm"
```

I need to replace the white-spaces with underscores, but only in the substrings that match a pattern. (In this case the pattern would be a semi-colon before and after.)

The expected output should be:

```
output = "askl jmsp wiqp;THIS_IS_A_MATCH; dlkasl das, fm"
```

Any ideas how to achieve that, preferably using regular expressions, and without splitting the string?

I tried:

```
gsub("(.*);(.*);(.*)", "\\2", input) # Pattern matching and
gsub(" ", "_", input) # Naive gsub
```

Couldn't put them both together though.

Comment: Based on the example, `gsub("(?<=[A-Z])\\s+", "_", input, perl = TRUE)` works

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew `gsub("(.*);(.*);(.*)", "\\2", input) # Pattern matching` and `gsub(" ", "_", input) # Naive gsub` .. Couldn't put them both together though..

Comment: Is the number of spaces unknown? If no, your approach will work.

Comment: @akrun Thanks alot! Can you please help me with understanding the solution?  Specially the `(?<=` part ?

Comment: @Dee: Akrun suggests to replace 1 or more whitespace symbols with underscore if they are preceded with an uppercase ASCII letter. Is that what you need?

Comment: @Dee It is not exactly the pattern you specified in the question, but based on the upper case letters followed by space

Comment: akrun WiktorStribiżew, Unfortunately not. The actual pattern is substrings that are between two separators (in this dummy example ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding the original question:

> Substitute character in a matching substring

You may do it easily with `gsubfn`:

```
> library(gsubfn)
> input = "askl jmsp wiqp;THIS IS A MATCH; dlkasl das, fm"
> gsubfn(";([^;]+);", function(g1) paste0(";",gsub(" ", "-", g1, fixed=TRUE),";"), input)
[1] "askl jmsp wiqp;THIS-IS-A-MATCH; dlkasl das, fm"
```

The `;([^;]+);` matches any string starting with `;` and up to the next `;` capturing the text in-between and then replacing the whitespaces with hyphens only inside the captured part.

Another approach is to use a PCRE regex with a `\G` based regex with `gsub`:

```
p = "(?:\\G(?!\\A)|;)(?=[^;]*;)[^;\\s]*\\K\\s"
> gsub(p, "-", input, perl=TRUE)
[1] "askl jmsp wiqp;THIS-IS-A-MATCH; dlkasl das, fm"
```

See the [online regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ukL2Pk/1)

**Pattern details**:

- `(?:\\G(?!\\A)|;)` - a custom boundary: either the end of the previous successful match (`\\G(?!\\A)`) or (`|`) a semicolon
- `(?=[^;]*;)` - a lookahead check: there must be a `;` after 0+ chars other than `;`
- `[^;\\s]*` - 0+ chars other than `;` and whitespaces
- `\\K` -  omitting the text matched so far
- `\\s` - 1 single whitespace character (*if multiple whitespaces are to be replaced with 1 hyphen, add `+` after it*).

Comment: Thanks alot @Wiktor